# Does the following Java code really contain cyclic dependency?

Tags: java

'

At a recent discussion within our team I had written the following code which was later flagged as having the cyclic dependency although to my knowledge and experience it is not. I need some fresh eyes to take a look at it so that I can learn more.

**disclaimer**: The production code was converted into the corresponding dummy code to avoid copyright issues. Main method (ofcourse) did not exist in the prod code.

*Beany.java*

```
public class Beany {

    private String x;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // main exists for testing purposes here. Depicts the functionality of validation function.
        List<BeanyValidator> validatorList = List.of(isConfigDataNull(),
                                                     isValueOfXEmpty());
        Beany beany = new Beany();
        beany.setX("");
        System.out.println(collectErrorsFrom(beany, validatorList));
    }

    public void setX(String x) { // setters in our code does not exist. This is merely for demo purposes here.
        this.x = x;
    }

    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

*BeanyValidator.java*:

```
public interface BeanyValidator extends Function<Beany, String> {

    static BeanyValidator isConfigDataNull() {
        return beany -> Objects.isNull(beany)
                               ? "Object is null!"
                               : "NO_ERROR";
    }

    static BeanyValidator isValueOfXEmpty() {
        return beany -> beany.getX().isEmpty()
                               ? "Value is empty!"
                               : "NO_ERROR";
    }

    static List<String> collectErrorsFrom(Beany beany, List<BeanyValidator> validators) {
        return validators.stream()
                         .map(validator -> validator.apply(beany))
                         .filter(err -> !"NO_ERROR".equals(err))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

What was pointed out as **circular dependency** was the fact `Beany` was being used as `Function<T,U>` -- making beany dependency of BeanyValidator -- and using validators inside the main method (which in prod is some sort of validation function) makes the validator a dependency of Beany and thereby causing **circular dependency.** I do not agree with my respectful peer but I always come into a discussion thinking I could be wrong.

By the way, I applied combinator pattern using Java8 Functions.
Could someone please some shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards.

Comment: Hi Progman, thank you so much for your input.

Comment: As a side note, `"NO_ERROR"` is a terrible return value. Consider return an Optional instead, which you can flatMap instead of using a filter on a magic string value

Comment: @Progman But the `Beany` class *does* use the `BeanyValidator` class, in the `main` method.

Comment: Hi @njzk2, it's actually some sort of enum in our code base. I just recreated the example to mimic correspondence.

Comment: In the production code, the main method does not exist, but something else does which references BeanyValidator, correct? Or no?

Comment: @Progman, I must re-highlight to you that the `main()` method does not exist. But there does exist a function called `validateXyz()` corresponding to the `main` method.

Comment: @ShayanAhmad if the function (regardless if it called `main()` or `validateXyz()`) is located in the `Beany` class and contains a `BeanyValidator` declaration then you have a cyclic dependency, see my answer below.

Comment: @ShayanAhmad Do you have such a method like `main()` (or `validateXyz()`) with **that** code, which references the `List<BeanyValidator>` type, inside your `Beany` class?

Comment: Yes there does exist something like that. And I am thinking to remove the 2nd parameter of `collectErrorsFrom` and put the necessary validations required inside the `collectErrorsFrom` method within `BeanyValidator` thereby removing `BeanyValidators` inside `Beany` and the call to that function would then just look like `collectErrorsFrom(beany)` while also renaming it to `validateAndCollectErrorsFrom(Beany beany)`. Would it then remove the cyclic dependency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a cyclic dependency:

- Class `Beany` has a `List<BeanyValidator>`
- Interface `BeanyValidator` extends `Function<Beany, String>`

This can be verified by putting the classes in different packages and then look at the import statements required for the code to compile. You will find that one class imports the other and vice versa.

One suggestion to break the circular dependency is to refactor the `main()` method from the `Beany` class to a separate class, e.g.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<BeanyValidator> validatorList = List.of(isConfigDataNull(),
                                                     isValueOfXEmpty());
        Beany beany = new Beany();
        beany.setX("");
        System.out.println(collectErrorsFrom(beany, validatorList));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer @matsev. Had the `validatorList` not created in the `main` method, would it then not become free of the cyclic dependency (like using `List.of` directly as the second parameter of `collectErrorsFrom` directly inside main? 

Also, the fellow developer highlighted that I should make the `BeanyValidator` class as the nested inner `enum` inside `Beany` class to avoid **cyclic dependency**. Would that be another solution?

Comment: @ShayanAhmad no, it would still have a circular dependency. matsev is misleading you by mentioning `import` and packages, which are utterly unrelated to the idea of cyclic deps. The question is: Can then code be compiled without it, and the answer is _no_, the `isConfigDataNull()` method is in BeanyValidator. Even if it wasn't, its returntype is `BeanyValidator`, and it needs to be that type for this code to work.

Comment: @ShayanAhmad The real answer is probably that, yeah, there is, but as long as the types are in the same package, so what? There are a billion-and-one "cyclic deps" of this nature in just about every major library under the sun. As long as the cyclic dep's "cover" (the types involved) are all highly correlated (at least in the same package, and perhaps more tightly bound together than that) - then trying to avoid that will probably lead to worse code (harder to maintain and read) than if you blindly adhere. Remember.. blind adherence to style rules = bad.

Comment: @ShayanAhmad using `List.of()` would not help as long as the list elements are of type `BeanyValidator` and you still have static imports of `isConfigDataNull()` and `isValueOfXEmpty()` from `BeanyValidator`. Yes, moving the `BeanyValidator` into the `Beamy` class would avoid the cyclic dependency as by doing so you will only have a single class containing both the `Beany` state and its validation logic.

Comment: How about if I move the validators inside the `BeanyValidator` itself leaving only `collectErrorsFrom(beany)` and nothing more in the `Beany`. I think, this way, the cyclic dependency could also be avoided. Your thoughts @matsev?

Comment: @ShayanAhmad There is a cyclic dependency as long as there is a cross references between `Beany` and `BeanyValidator` and they are implemented in separate files. There are three possible solutions: A - create a new class and move all `BeanyValidator` references from `Beany` to it , B - merge `Beany` and `BeanyValidator` to a single class, C - move all `BeanyValidator` references from `Beany` to `BeanyValidator`

Comment: @matsev, if I go with the `C` option and `BeanyValidator.validateAndCollectErrors` takes `Beany` as an argument to be validated against. Would it still be *circularly dependent* because of calling of `validateAndCollectErrors` inside `Beany`?

Comment: @ShayanAhmad If `validateAndCollectErrors()` is a static method in `BeanyValidator` that is called from `Beany`? Then yes, you have a reference from `Beany` to `BeanyValidator` and since `BeanyValidator` contains `Beany` you still have cross references between the two.